# Ceedling doesn't create Rakefile

Tags: unit-testing, rakefile, ceedling

I am trying to use Ceedling to create unit tests for my C-project. 
I wrote in terminal:
-ceedling new My_Project_Name
Ceedling creates a folder with name "My_Project_Name". But there is no Rakefile in this folder. What's wrong?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rakefile when creating new project in New version of Ceedling. Just use `ceedling module:create[new_test]` and `ceedling test:all` instead.

Just refer to this link:
https://www.liuguogy.com/archives/Unity-C-build-system-Ceedling.html

Answer (score 0):

To run the tests you just use the command

```
ceedling
```

without any arguments. The rakefile is located in the vendor directory (I think) if you want to see it but you shouldn't need to alter it.

Comment: The ceedling github page (https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling/blob/master/docs/CeedlingPacket.md) describes how to use the command.